# Implicit conversion to match operator argument

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I have the following class declaration:

```
class DepthDescriptor
{
public:
    DepthDescriptor(DepthType depth);
    bool operator==(DepthDescriptor& type);
    bool operator>=(DepthDescriptor& type);
    bool operator<=(DepthDescriptor& type);
...
}
```

Why does the following line not perform an implicit conversion to the `DepthDescriptor` object so that the operator comparison can take place?

```
if (depth == Depth_8U)
{
...
}
```

Note that `depth` is a `DepthDescriptor` object, `DepthType` is an enum, and `Depth_8U` is one of the enum values. I was hoping that lines like the one above would first call the implicit constructor `DepthDescriptor(DepthType depth)` and then the appropriate operator, but I'm getting `no operator "==" matches these operands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bool operator==(const DepthDescriptor& type) const;
bool operator>=(const DepthDescriptor& type) const;
bool operator<=(const DepthDescriptor& type) const;
```

Comment: Why not making the functions `const` as well?

Comment: Better still try `bool operator==(const DepthDescriptor& type) const;` Or even better make these operators global functions, `bool operator==(const DepthDescriptor& lhs, const DepthDescriptor& rhs)`

Comment: Yes, should make the functions const.

Answer (score 0):

To get the conversion to happen you should write global functions not member functions, and you should be const-correct. I.e.

```
bool operator==(const DepthDescriptor& lhs, const DepthDescriptor& rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

Conversions will not happen on the left hand side if you use member functions. Conversions may not happen in a standard conformant compiler unless you are const-correct.

Comment: The above answer was correct, but I'd like to know why you said that the conversion wouldn't work.

Comment: To automatically convert the compiler has to create a temporary `DepthDescriptor` object. It's a rule of C++ that you cannot bind a temporary object to a non-const reference. Not all compilers enforce this rule however. With the member function version of your operators `x == y` is in effect `x.operator==(y)`. In this code C++ specifies different rules for what types are acceptable for `x` and `y`. In particular it will not do implicit conversions on `x`. The global function method is better because it is *symmetric* and the same rules (including implicit conversions) apply to x and y.